# Curl: Returns weird output than expected, but why?

Tags: shell, curl

I'm using curl to check if I can reach a specific document on one of my proxy servers.
When checked if the proxy is a member of the load balancer, the check is made against this file.

Example:

```
[root@PRX scripts]# curl http://`hostname`:8080/proxy/keepalive?file=/workspace/temp/1.txt
ppp
[root@PRX scripts]#
```

This output is intended.

If I try to compare this output, the test is false:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp=$(curl http://$(hostname):8080/proxy/keepalive?file=/workspace/temp/1.txt)
echo $tmp
if [ "$tmp" = "ppp" ]; then
    echo "Match"
else
    echo "No match"
fi
```

I ran the script using debug mode (`bash -x`):

```
[root@PRX scripts]# bash -x testscript
+++ hostname
++ curl 'http://XXXXX.com:8080/proxy/keepalive?file=/workspace/temp/1.txt'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     5    0     5    0     0   2326      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5000
+ tmp=$'ppp\r'
+ echo $'ppp\r'
ppp
+ [[ $'ppp\r' = ppp ]]
+ echo 'No match'
No match
[root@PRX scripts]#
```

I also tried writing the output of `curl` to a temp file in `/tmp/tmp` and then `cat` the file but I get the same response. You can see in the debug output that the `$tmp` variable, which holds the output of `curl` shows

```
tmp=$'ppp\r'
```

instead of

```
tmp='ppp'
```

Can anyone please shed some light on the subject and explain this behavior?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: You added `-o tmp` to your variable assignment `curl` command. That tells curl to send output to the file and not stdout. Command substitution catches stdout contents. If you need/want both you want to use `tee`.

Comment: It was actually just another try, I get the exact same response when not using the '-o' switch.

Comment: Are you sure the server is giving you consistent results? Because if the curl command sends a string to stdout then command substitution will catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\r` is a carriage return, and it's there because the web server returns DOS line terminators.

You can strip them with `tr`:

```
TMP=$(curl "http://$HOSTNAME:8080/proxy/keepalive?file=/workspace/temp/1.txt" | tr -d '\r')
if [[ $TMP = ppp ]]
then 
  echo "It's true"
fi
```